# Activities not coming back after unfollowing actor who cc ed them

Tags: getstream-io

My Data is structured into Posts which get created by users and are written into topics. 
Both Creators an topics can be followed. As soon as a creator writes a post and attaches a topic the post gets put into the feed of the creator and in the feed of the topic.
As soon as a topic or a creator gets followed everything works correctly. But if I first follow a topic, then follow a creator who created posts into this topic and unfollow the creator I won't receive the activities anymore even if I'm still following the topic. 
Is this intended or am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't I use the to (cc) functionality this way?

Answer (score 0):

When you send an unfollow command, there's a flag you can set that leaves old activities in the user's feed. If you've tried setting that flag and it hasn't worked, please let us know which SDK you're using and we'll help track it down.

Comment: Does this keep the history of the creator aswell? So for example i follow dogs as topics the creator published to posts to dogs and one to cat i so if i unfollow the creator there should only the dog posts left as im not following the cats topic but that cat post would be in the history of the creator

Comment: Yes, the topic feed would keep its copy. When a user's timeline follows another feed (another user, a topic, etc), any activities written into that topic feed get copied into the timeline feed. When you unfollow, we delete any activities in the timeline feed that came from from the topic feed, unless you explicitly tell us to retain them. Unfollowing a topic feed does not delete anything from the original topic feed itself.